# Diagonalization of Markov matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, matrix-decomposition, stochastic-matrices

If we're given a $ \displaystyle  2 \times 2 $  Markov matrix (so all entries are non-negative and columns add to 1) **M**$(a,b)$ such that $$M = M(a,b) := \begin{bmatrix}1 - a & b\\a & 1 - b \end{bmatrix}$$ where $a$ and $b$ are $ 0 ≤ a ≤ 1, 0 ≤ b ≤ 1$, why can $M(a,b)$ always be diagonalized? I'm confused as to why this is the case, and wouldn't this mean that higher powers of $M$ will always approach a rank one matrix?

Comment: Have you tried diagonalizing it?

Comment: See the [Perron Frobenius theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem)